# Set height content, footer that extends the rest of the browser height

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky-footer

So I know the first thought is "Sticky Footer", but that's not really the case. It's the footer height that's the variable.

I have a page where the main content is 200px margin from the top... after the content, I need the footer to extend all the way down for the remainder of the browser height; there will be a 1600px background image that will `repeat-x`

Comment: how large is the page content generally?  Will the user ever scroll the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one trick.  Make your header, content, and footer as you normally would.  Set the height of the footer to 100% and give it the `position:fixed` attribute, and make sure that you *don't* give it a top, bottom, etc.  attribute.  This will take the footer "out of flow" but leave it right where it would be naturally (this removes any ugly scroll bars).

you can see it in action in the [example demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/SnyLg/).

Comment: You know, the only CSS properties that I've been a but unsure about are the position ones. Thanks a lot, Joseph!

Comment: @dcolumbus You're welcome. :) They're really useful when you get used to them actually.  Glad I could help.

Comment: This doesn't work on pages that DO have a lot of content. The footer just gets shoved into oblivion. I think most people will need a solution that works in either case.

Comment: @RampantCreativeGroup At that point such a use case diverges from the original scenario. In that case, just have a regular footer that doesn't use positioning at all. So yes, most cases this doesn't work, but only because most cases are normal scenarios with normal footers that expand with content like a normal element on the page.  Now, if you need both to work, usually a good background on the html element will suffice, but as I understand the OP's case to be, the background needed to start at the top of the footer. It's a unique case (not to mention hacky), which required a unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make `body` have the `background-image` of the footer?

Then, you can set the main content to have whatever background you like, and the footer will appear to extend to the rest of the page.

Comment: There's a gradient in the footer image. It would have to be pixel perfect every single time the page renders for it to show up correctly. You'd notice.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/JFtwD/25/
Here is how you could do it. Don't know if it is the best solution, but it is a solution.

Comment: It would be a good ideer to put a min-height on the footer aswell.
Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JFtwD/28/